# How to disable the register DLL build step of my DLL project in VS2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm getting this error

```
error PRJ0050: Failed to register output.  Please try enabling Per-user Redirection or register the component from a command prompt with elevated permissions.
```

I don't really need to register the DLL as part of the build, where can I disable that step from the project configuration?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it, I needed to set "Linker Settings"->"Register Output" to false.